# Spring service class extends AbstractService and implements interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

This is my first project using spring and I had many problems but this is first which I can't solve using google. And I would like to ask you for help.

I would like to have AbstractService:

```
@Service
public abstract class AbstractService {

@Autowired
private DatabaseRepository repository;

public void add(...) {
    ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<AbstractEntity> getByCriteria(...) {
    ...
}
}
```

Then I would like to have interface for each service to provide methods adding criteria to search

```
public interface DateServiceInterface {

void addEqualCriterion(LocalDate equal);

void addYoungerThanCriterion(LocalDate date);

void addOlderThanCriterion(LocalDate date);

void addBetweenCriterion(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);

}
```

and finally I would like to have service which I would like to use as autowired

```
@Transactional
@Service("DateService")
public class DateService extends AbstractService implements DateServiceInterface {

private ArrayList<Criterion> dateCriterions = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(Date date) {
    ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Date> getByCriteria() {
    ...
}

@Override
public void addEqualCriterion(LocalDate equal) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void addYoungerThanCriterion(LocalDate date) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void addOlderThanCriterion(LocalDate date) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void addBetweenCriterion(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    ...
}
}
```

In main method I would like to have:

```
DateService service = (DateService) context.getBean("DateService");
```

but it results in:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33 cannot be cast to project.service.DateService
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong... Without DateServiceInterface it works. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Spring proxies your bean to support `@Transactional`. In this case it used JDK proxies, that don't support your target bean's concrete class, only its interfaces. So you should be accessing it as a `DateServiceInterface` retrieved through `context.getBean("DateService", DateServiceInterface.class)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can tell Spring to use CGLIB proxies.

Comment: But how to call methods from DateService which are not declared in AbstractService and DateServiceInterface?

Comment: You won't be able to (and you probably shouldn't) through JDK proxies. Use CGLIB proxies or rethink your design.

Comment: Ok, thank you. You said it is impossible and I have changed my design and it works :)